# How do I know what is the type of control textbox/checkbox etc in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to be dynamically build controls like textbox, checkbox, radiobutton etc by making a Ajax request and downloading the HTML. However once enough controls are on the screen and user submits the form, I need all the controls and it's posted values. Posted values are easy to get using Non sequential indices in Asp.Net MVC. But, how do I get which control's value it is? Put simply if the form has submitted the value "Hello World". I need to be able to know from where did the Hello World. Was the textbox that submitted this value or the textarea?

I don't need anything else like ID, name etc. Just need to know the type of control whether it was texbox, textarea, select or which one.

Comment: standard Server side you can't. You need to remember that in MVC it uses standard HTTP Request Response model, unlike Webforms where the context of the sending element, etc. is maintained through ViewState. So from a Request Response point of view all you have to play with is the name of the element sending the data and the data itself.

Best thing I can think to do it append the sending form element type into the name of the element, this seems a bit messy though. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Liam you should post that as an answer IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you dynamically build these client elements, you give them a name so they will post to the server.
just follow a naming convention like:
textarea1,textarea2...
txt1,txt2,...
then at the server, to collect the values - take all the keys that start with textarea to collect the values of textAreas...

a nicer way will be to have a model with lists for each type, and when you generate the client elements, build their names so the values will be mapped to the correct list by the ModelBinder
the syntax for these names is a bit nasty so work with client templates
[I used this post by haacked when i needed to build something like this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need know more about http get or post.